# Cut path in object

Tags: inkscape

is possible to cut text in object in Inkscape? Let's say I have 3 text objects, and I want to cut outline of these object in another object, not classic rectangle or circle but some complex object for example some object traced from bitmap. Thanks You!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible using a Mask:

1. Make sure the trace is in a group, or that all artwork you wish to affect is grouped.
2. Draw a white filled rectangle with no stroke, over the artwork, to completely cover it, then move it out of the way, so that you can see what you are doing next
3. Type some black text over the artwork. You can have as many text objects as you want, or you can even use other objects, as long as they are black. If you just want the outline of the text, then instead apply a black stroke to  the text, and set the fill to white
4. Move the white rectangle back, to cover the artwork
5. Select the white rectangle and all the text, and other objects if they are to be part of the mask, and group them. This will be the mask
6. Select both groups, i.e. the mask and the artwork group, then click *Object > Mask > Set*

Here's an example of a trace with text cut out using a mask, I've enabled the transparency background so you can see it more clearly.

[image]

How the mask works is that everything that is white in the mask group remains opaque, while everything that is black is fully transparent. Shades of grey can also be used for semi-transparency in the mask.